# Is it better to import controllers or models in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

In a CakePHP application, is it better to import Controllers that have access to models or the Models themselves?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never import controllers. Controllers are simply "hubs" that *control* the data flow/input-output, they don't *do* anything by themselves. You shouldn't have any important, unique logic or data in controllers, and hence should never have a need to import them. Controllers are also not *the interface* to models or anything like that. In fact, you should decouple your models from the controller as much as possible. If you're interested in the model, import the model.

Comment: For some added clarity, trying replace occurrences of "controller" with "user flow" and "model" with "data" in deceze's answer and read it again. :) "If you're interested in the data, import the data." An example of something that imports models, and not controllers, would be a CakePHP shell (specifically the `$uses` part) http://book.cakephp.org/view/110/Creating-Shells-Tasks

Answer (score 0):

definitely the models